# R: select and change the name of an object in a script that appears multiple times (shortcut?)

Tags: r, rstudio, shortcut

I would like to know if there is a shortcut to change the name of an object in Rstudio that appears multiple times in a script. For example, if I start with:

```
x*y
y <- x + 4
x <- x + y
```

This is just some meaningless code. Suppose I would like to have z instead of x :

```
z*y
y <- z + 4
z <- z + y
```

Is there a way of changing all the x to z silmultaneously , instead of one at the time? This would be very useful for longer scripts.

Comment: I'm confused. The point of a variable is to assign it arbitrary values. So if `x <- 1` and `z <- 2` then `x <- z` should work.

Comment: Is Ctrl-Alt-Shift-M // Rename in Scope in Rstudio what you want?

Comment: I know I can just assign z to x and then use the same script, but what I want is just to change all the x to z in the script, literally speaking! I'm just hoping there is some kind of simple shortcut to do that.

Comment: Yes, rename in scope works thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you like to change x to z in Rstudio

1. press [Ctrl] + [f]
2. put the name of the old variable... in your case press just [x]
3. press [tab] to change to the 'replace' field
4. put the name of the new variable name

Take care that you dont change, when the string is **only part** of other functions or variables

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ctrl + Alt + shift + M` for this in Rstuido.
You can also look at some more key board shortcuts like that using `Alt + Shift +K`